# How do you get JavaScript to alert a Razor variable?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create a table header that alerts its text when clicked. I could not pass in a Razor variable to a JavaScript function parameter. What's a good work-around?

Here is my code:

```
@foreach (var web in Model.Webinars)
{
    var title = web.Filename;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
        // If filename is too long, shorten it
        if (title.Length > 10)
        {
            title = title.Substring(0, 10) + "...";
        }
        // Create a header that alerts when clicked
        // Errors if I pass @title in alert()
        <th onclick="alert(@title)">@title</th>
    }
}
```

I get an error that looks like this:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 71, column 34 in 
http://localhost:64023/Webinar/Reports\n\nSCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
```

Comment: Try `<th onclick="alert('@title')">@title</th>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `@title` in quotes

```
<th onclick="alert('@title')">@title</th>
```

Comment: ...this is because `@title` is like a macro that is text replaced with the contents of that string.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Satpal's answer is half right, you need to wrap @title in quotes, like

```
<th onclick="alert('@title')">@title</th>
```

but you also need to wrap `<th>` in `<table>` element like below, otherwise it still not work.

```
<table>
    <th onclick="alert('@title')">@title</th>
</table>
```

Comment: OP has not posted complete code. As OP is using `@foreach` he must be iterating and creating table header